# Matrix rank and amount of regressors

Tags: econometrics, matrix

A question states: $X$ is the vector of regressors stacked for 30 observations and $Rank(X)=5$. There are no lags of $y_t$ in the set $X_t$. Using the Durbin-Watson statistic, test the null hypothesis of no autocorrelation at a 5% significance level.

They then execute the DW test with $k=4$. As far as I know, this is the amount of regressors right? How can it be 4 (and not 5) when the matrix rank of $X$ is 5?